# Processing word document using OpenXML and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, openxml

So I'm trying to populate the content controls in a word document by matching the Tag and populating the text within that content control.

The following displays in a MessageBox all of the tags I have in my document.

```
//Create a copy of the template file and open the document
File.Delete(hhscDocument);
File.Copy(hhscTemplate, hhscDocument, true);

//Open the word document specified by location
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(hhscDocument, true))
{

    //Change the document type from template to document
    var mainDocument = document.MainDocumentPart.Document;
    if (mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Tag>().Any())
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Table>().Count().ToString());
        var tags = mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Tag>().ToList();
        var aString = string.Empty;
        foreach(var tag in tags)
        {
            aString += string.Format("{0}{1}", tag.Val, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(aString);
    }
}
```

However when I try the following it doesn't work.

```
//Create a copy of the template file and open the document
File.Delete(hhscDocument);
File.Copy(hhscTemplate, hhscDocument, true);

//Open the word document specified by location
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(hhscDocument, true))
{

    //Change the document type from template to document
    var mainDocument = document.MainDocumentPart.Document;
    if (mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Tag>().Any())
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Table>().Count().ToString());
        var tags = mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Tag>().ToList();
        var bString = string.Empty;
        foreach(var tag in tags)
        {
            bString += string.Format("{0}{1}", tag.Parent.GetFirstChild<Text>().Text, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(bString);
    }
}
```

My objective in the end is if I match the appropriate tag I want to populate/change the text in the content control that tag belongs to.

Comment: What don't work in your code ? the bstring is empty ?

Comment: @MaximePorté I've noticed it doesn't process when you do not give the correct path to the text field. The main problem is the XML is different with certain content controls versus others. Event if they're the same type. This is due to the structure of the document.

Answer (score 0):

So I basically used FirstChild and InnerXml to pick apart the documents XML contents. From there I developed the following that does what I need.

```
//Open the word document specified by location
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(hhscDocument, true))
{       
    var mainDocument = document.MainDocumentPart.Document;
    if (mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Tag>().Any())
    {
        //Find all elements(descendants) of type tag
        var tags = mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Tag>().ToList();

        //Foreach of these tags
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            //Jump up two levels (.Parent.Parent) in the XML element and then jump down to the run level
            var run = tag.Parent.Parent.Descendants<Run>().ToList();

            //I access the 1st element because there is only one element in run
            run[0].GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = "<new_text_value>";
        }
    }
    mainDocument.Save();
}
```

This finds all the tags inside of your document and stores the elements in a list

```
var tags = mainDocument.Body.Descendants<Tag>().ToList();
```

This part of the code starts off at the tag part of the xml. From there I call parent twice to jump up two levels in the XML code so I can gain access to the Run level using descendants.

```
var run = tag.Parent.Parent.Descendants<Run>().ToList();
```

And last but not least the following code stores a new value into the text part of the PlainText Content control.

```
run[0].GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = "<new_text_value>";
```

Things that I noticed is the xml hierarchy is a funky thing. I find it easier to access these things from bottom up, hence why I started with the tags and moved up.